# Function to extract numeric values only

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to make a function in c# which accept only numeric values. I used below lines of code=

```
 Regex rgx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]");
             string str2= rgx.Replace(str, "");
```

But if I $123.45 then it convert to 12345. I need it as 123.45.
If I do enter as 123.00 it should be as 123

Comment: Your regex removes `.` and `,` as well. Why not add them to the list, eg `"[^a-zA-Z0-9 -\.,]"` ?

Comment: Include the period in your regex and then round to the nearest int.

Comment: If you're displaying decimal places for numbers that have fractional components, then you should do the same for numbers that don't -- e.g. "123.00".  That's the convention in every discipline I know of.